# Direct3D shader compilation fails with constant buffers

Tags: directx, shaders, hlsl, asset-creation

I've been particularly annoyed by a 'bug' for a couple days involving [D3DCompile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and vertex shaders with constant buffers. I'm assuming the bug is my fault (missing flag or small nuance of the poorly documented API).

During my asset compile process I compile this vertex shader:

```
cbuffer Frame : register(b0) {
  float4x4 model_view_proj;
  float4x4 inv_model;
  float4x4 inv_view;
  float4x4 inv_projection;
};

struct VS_INPUT {
  float3 position  : POSITION;
  float2 tex_coord : TEXCOORD0;
  float3 normal    : NORMAL;
  float3 binormal  : BINORMAL;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT {
  float4 position  : POSITION;
  float2 tex_coord : TEXCOORD0;
};

VS_OUTPUT vs_main( VS_INPUT IN )
{
  VS_OUTPUT OUT;
  OUT.position = mul(IN.position, Frame.model_view_proj);
  OUT.tex_coord = IN.tex_coord;
  return OUT;
}
```

With this code:

```
const D3D_SHADER_MACRO defines[] = {
  { "VERTEX_SHADER", "1" },
  { "D3D11",         "1" },
  { NULL, NULL },
};

D3DCompile(
  src, src_len,
  path,
  &defines[0],
  &include,
  "vs_main",
  "vs_4_0",
  D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY |
  D3DCOMPILE_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL0 |
  D3DCOMPILE_PACK_MATRIX_ROW_MAJOR, 0,
  &blob,
  &error_msg_blob
)
```

I have verified (by stepping through) that my ID3DInclude implementation works and all input data is correct. However, I receive a E_FAIL with an associated error message:

```
error X3004: undeclared identifier 'Frame'
```

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constant buffers don't create a namespace; their members are visible at global scope.  So instead of `Frame.model_view_proj` you just want `model_view_proj`.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense in retrospect; it's a natural extension to DX9.